# Is $A=\{ \{k\};k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a monotone class?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is $A=\{ \{k\};k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a monotone class ?

In fact, if $A_i\in A$ and $A_{1}\subset A_{2}\subset\cdots$, then $A_1=A_2=\cdots, \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=A_1\in A.$

The same can be said for $A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots.$

However, I'm puzzled because this familiy of sets doesn't seem monotonous.
If I admit this, most familiy of sets  would be monotone class.
Am I defining the monotone class wrong ?

Comment: The most important word in the question is "seem".  A major value of precise, mathematical reasoning (as in the first part of your question) is that it can correct our notions of what *seems* to be the case. (And part of the importance of definitions in mathematics is that they replace our preconceptions about what words, like "monotone", *ought* to mean.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a monotone class, because, as you say, the only monotone sequences of elements are a repeated singleton, so for some $k$, $A_n = \{k\}$ for all $n$. And then the union or intersection is that same set $\{k\}$. So the condition is satisfied, indeed almost trivially. Also $\mathcal{M}=\emptyset$ is a monotone class voidly (we quantify $\forall$ over no sequences at all). These singletons form a slightly more interesting case (it does require a little thought). But a monotone class it is!

Monotone is not meant as *strictly* monotone. We just require that either for all $n$, $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$ (monotone increasing) or for all $n$, $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ (monotone decreasing). Not $\subsetneq$; equality is permitted. But even if that *were* the definition, then your $\mathcal{M}$ does not have any strictly monotone sequences at all and then the condition is again true by voidness: there are no sequences to check, so it's true for all relevant sequences..